# Suppose $Y \sim Ber(X)$ where $X = F(Z)$ and $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. What is the expected value $E[Y-X]$?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $Y \sim Ber(X)$ where $X = F(Z)$ and $Z \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. $F$ denotes the cdf of some continuous random variable.  What is the expected value $E[Y-X]$?

\begin{align*}
E[Y-X] &= E[Y]-E[X]\\
&= E[E[Y|X]] - E[X]\\
&= E[F(Z)] - E[F(Z)]\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Is the above correct?

Comment: Are the $Z$s considered as random variables or a *realizations* of a random variable? Stated differently, are the two $Z$ quantities the outcome of the same random experiment or two different ones?

Comment: The $Z$ is a random variable.

Comment: You can simplify your question further and make it even more general: let $X$ be any random variable supported on the interval $[0,1]$ and let "$Y \sim Ber(X),$" as you write.  The question is whether $E[Y]=E[X].$ According to standard measure-theoretic definitions (in which a conditional probability distribution is defined in terms of conditional expectations), there's nothing to show, because this equality essentially *is* the definition.  Thus, you must have in mind some other definition of what "$Y \sim Ber(X)$" means.  What is it?

Comment: Typically for a bernoulli-distributed r.v. $Y$, its mean is fixed, i.e., $Y \sim Ber(p)$ where $p$ is a constant between 0 and 1. In this case, if the mean of $Y$ is a random variable $X$, I wasn't sure whether that changes anything. And so I thought I had to invoke the tower rule $E[Y] = E[E[Y|X]]$

Comment: If you're considering $Z$ and therefore $X$ as a random variable I agree with @whuber 's comment, this essential *is* the definition of a conditional expectation. Unless there is something else omitted from the problem description though the $Z$s are not relevant to the question. For example, if $F(\cdot)$ was the cdf of the $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then this would be equivalent to $X \sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$. I'm still confused about why the $Z$ random variables are included.

Comment: I'm confused too.  If Z is any r.v. with CDF F, then X = F(Z) $\sim$ Unif(0,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is correct (assuming that $F$ is fixed), but it can be simplified, generalised, and made more explicit.  Let's start by generalising your model and writing it in a more explicit form:

$$\begin{align}
Y|Z &\sim \text{Bern}(F(Z)), \\[6pt]
Z &\sim \text{Dist}, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\text{Dist}$ is some arbitrary distribution.  Since $Y|Z \sim \text{Bern}(F(Z))$ we have the conditional expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y|Z) = 0 \cdot (1-F(Z)) + 1 \cdot F(Z) = F(Z).$$

Using the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) we then have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y-F(Z))
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y-F(Z)|Z)) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}( F(Z) - F(Z) ) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(0) \\[6pt]
&= 0. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Observe that this result does not require any assumption about the distribution of $Z$.